# ConcurrentMap#putIfAbsent with Scala Int's

Tags: scala, concurrenthashmap

[java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html#putIfAbsent(K,%20V))'s `putIfAbsent` docs say the following about the return type:

> the previous value associated with the specified key, or null if there was no mapping for the key.

On Scala 2.10.4, I tried to call `putIfAbsent(Int, Int)`, i.e. with Scala's `Int` type.

```
scala> import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap

scala> new ConcurrentHashMap[Int, Int]()
res0: java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap[Int,Int] = {}

scala> val x: Int = 1
x: Int = 1
```

Since `1` does not exist in the empty `ConcurrentHashMap`, I would expect `null` to return from a `putIfAbsent(x, x)` call.

```
scala> res0.putIfAbsent(x, x)
res1: Int = 0
```

But, `0` gets returned. I'm assuming that `null` gets converted to `0`.

What exactly is going on here? It seems odd to me that it's compiling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Int` cannot be `null`, nor can any `AnyVal`. From the [scaladoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Null):

> Null is a subtype of all reference types; its only instance is the null reference. Since Null is not a subtype of value types, null is not a member of any such type. For instance, it is not possible to assign null to a variable of type scala.Int.

If we try it directly, we'll get an error:

```
scala> val i: AnyVal = null
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Null(null)
 required: AnyVal
Note that implicit conversions are not applicable because they are ambiguous:
 both method RichException in object Predef of type (self: Throwable)RichException
 and method augmentString in object Predef of type (x: String)scala.collection.immutable.StringOps
 are possible conversion functions from Null(null) to AnyVal
       val i: AnyVal = null
```

The compiler instead fills it with the default value for `Int`, which is `0`.

For example:

```
scala> def getNull[A](i: A): A = null.asInstanceOf[A]
getNull: [A](i: A)A

scala> getNull(1)
res6: Int = 0
```

Behind the scenes, we can't actually cast `null` to an `Int`, but it can be cast to a boxed type. However, once we use the boxed type in a context where it should be like the primitive it contains, it's converted to that type, which requires a default value.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer. You explained how a Scala `Int` can't be `null`. Given the Scala method: `def f(x: Int): java.lang.Integer` and a Java method, `public static int g`, is true that `f( g )` will **never** return `null`?

Comment: `java.lang.Integer` is a class, so it can be `null`.

Comment: Yes, it does. Sorry for the delay. Thanks for your help on all of my questions.